# iOS Swift + Parse User Sign up not passing any data to parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I do not get any errors and the application builds fine but when I check parse, there is no new user added. here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!

    //@IBOutlet var messageLabel: UILabel!


    @IBAction func loginVerifyButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        var pwdEntered = passwordTextField.text

        var emlEntered = emailTextField.text

        if pwdEntered != "" && emlEntered != "" {

            // If not empty then yay, do something

            func userSignUp() {

                var user = PFUser()
                user.email = emlEntered
                user.password = pwdEntered
                user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if let error = error {
                        let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
                        // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.

                    } else {
                        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                    }
                }

            }

        }else {

            //self.messageLabel.text = "All Fields Required"

        }
```

Comment: Did you try to add username for PFUser?

Comment: if you set an Xcode breakpoint at the "`if let error = error`" line, does it hit when you press the loginVerify button?  Also, `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` is meant for creating a new account, but your function name is `loginVerifyButton`.  [There's a separate PFUser method for logging in](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/logInWithUsername:password:error:), which exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Is this on iOS9? App Transport Security is enabled in the last few betas so you need to add exceptions for parse in your info.plist. Here's a good article to set it up if you are running iOS 9: http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Comment: I am actually trying to let the user login. I do not intend on using usernames - just email and password to log the user in. Is that not possible? Do i need to have a user-name for the users? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the userName of the PFUser as well, you are only setting the email and passwrod, but you should do this, ObjC, sorry:

```
  PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
  user.password = [[[self contentView] passwordField] text];
  user.email = [[[self contentView] emailField] text];
  user.username = [[[self contentView] emailField] text];
```

and then doing this:

```
 [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
       //do work
    } else {
      //bad stuff
    }
}];
```

Just set the userName to the the email address
AND if you read the header files for Parse API, you find this:

```
 @abstract Signs up the user *asynchronously*.

 @discussion This will also enforce that the username isn't already taken.

 @warning Make sure that password and username are set before calling this method.

 @param block The block to execute.
 It should have the following argument signature: `^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)`.
 */
- (void)signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:(PF_NULLABLE PFBooleanResultBlock)block;
```

This means that you must have a userName declared in the PFUser. So, change from this:

```
var user = PFUser()
user.email = emlEntered
user.password = pwdEntered
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
```

to this:

```
func myMethod() {
  var user = PFUser()
  user.username = "myUsername"
  user.password = "myPassword"
  user.email = "email@example.com"
  // other fields can be set just like with PFObject
  user["phone"] = "415-392-0202"

  user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
      let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
      // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
    } else {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    }
  }
}
```

from Parse's web site itself

Comment: Any way I can get the swift code for this? Do I need to have a user name? I was planning on having the sign up and login with email and password only.

Comment: uhh, yeah, give me until the morning, I've got a ton of coding going on, that's in like 6 hours and I'll post something for you, actually here's a snippet for you, reread my ansawer, this should get you started

Comment: I am pretty new to ios dev and I find the swift code to be more user friendly....sorry :) thanks for your help Larcerax

Comment: Yep, not problem, I still haven't had time to look at it, but you are okay

Comment: Oh yea, and I remember, I put the answer that SHOULD work at the end of my answer, take a look at that

Comment: it starts with  this "func myMethod() {"